# Pivotal method to verify a confidence interval for $\theta$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

Let $X$  be a random variable with p.d.f.: $$f(X|\theta) = \frac{e^{x-\theta}}{(1+e^{x-\theta})^2}$$
where $-\infty<x<\infty$ and $-\infty<\theta<\infty$

Use the pivotal method to verify that if $0<\alpha_1<0.5$ and $0<\alpha_2<0.5$, then

$[Y-\log(\frac{1-\alpha_2}{\alpha_2}),Y-\log(\frac{\alpha_1}{1+\alpha_1})]$ is a confidence interval for $\theta$ with converge probability $1-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)$
here my attempt
if I set $Y = X-\theta$
I get this $$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
F_Y(y) \equiv \mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant y) 
&= \mathbb{P}({X-\theta} \leqslant y) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X \leqslant y+\theta) \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_{-\infty}^{y+\theta} \frac{e^{x-\theta}}{(1+e^{x-\theta})^2} dx \\[6pt]
&= \Bigg[ \frac{-1}{1+e^{x-\theta}} \Bigg]_{x=-\infty}^{x=y+\theta} \\[6pt]
&= 1-\frac{1}{1+e^{y}}. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$
from this I derived the pdf equal to $$\frac{e^y}{(1+e^y)^2}$$

from this I show that the distribution does not depend on the parameter anymore. how can I show the confidence interval for $\theta$

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $Y$ ? Where are you stuck ?

Comment: what I do not understand is how Can I set this Y such that the distribution does not depend on $\theta$? I would say $Y = x-\theta$ but I do not know if this leads me to any conclusions.

Comment: Okay, your question is slighlty confusing because you gave the statement of the problem without specifying what $Y$ was supposed to be, but it's quite clear it's supposed to be a pivot quantity. If so then yes $Y=X-\theta$ works : can you check that the pdf of $Y$ is independent of $\theta$ ? Can you give a confidence interval for $Y$ of level $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ ?

Comment: once I set $Y = x-\theta$ the pdf becomes $$\frac{e^{y}}{(1+e^{y})^2}$$                             how can I give a confidence interval for $Y$?